# User-input values in first column with squares displayed in second column for multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, integer-arithmetic

A small help is needed regarding multi-dimensional arrays in C language. I am trying to compute square of each value, entered by user. However, I want both the value and results displayed as output.

I am looking for something like in this format for only specific rows and cols:

```
Value Squared

5     25
4     16
12    144
20    400
1000  1000000
```

So far I have come up with the following code, but it yields the error - "invalid operands to binary *(have 'int*' and 'int*'):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define ROWS 5  //number of defined rows
    #define COLS 2  //number of defined columns

    int main(void)
    {
       int square[ROWS][COLS];
       int row, col, temp;
       printf("VALUE       SQUARED\n");
       for(row=0; row<ROWS; row++) 
       {
       //one row at a time
           printf("Enter value for square[%d]: ", row);
           scanf("%d", &square[row][1]);     //only first column with user-input
           temp = square[row]*square[row];   //compute square of each value
           printf("%5d %15d\n", square[row][temp]);
       }
      //printing values of an array
      for(row=0; row<ROWS; row++)
          for(col=0; col<COLS; col++)
            printf("\t%d", square[row][col]);
      printf("\n");

      return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, "invalid operands to binary (have 'int' and 'int*')" caused by expression `square[row]*square[row]` where `square[row]` using only one index, so type of `int*` is trying to be squared. The second index required to have type `int`.

But ...

Why do you use `temp` as index?

Instead of

```
temp = square[row]*square[row];
printf("%5d %15d\n", square[row][temp]);
```

should be

```
square[row][0] = square[row][1]*square[row][1];
printf("%5d %15d\n", square[row][1], square[row][0]);
```

And pay attention, that in my example `square[row][0]` is uses (with [0]), but actually I suppose that you intended to use `square[row][0]` for VALUE and `square[row][1]` for SQUARED, but you forgot about the fact that in C indexing starts from `0`. So to have last part of your code working properly change "input part" and bring the output of the header to the table in place immediately before the "output part"

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 5  //number of defined rows
#define COLS 2  //number of defined columns

int main(void)
{
   int square[ROWS][COLS];
   int row, col, temp;

   // "input part"
   for(row=0; row<ROWS; row++) 
   {
       // TODO: type this again after reading my aswer above
   }
   // "output part"
   printf("VALUE       SQUARED\n");
   for(row=0; row<ROWS; row++)
   {
      for(col=0; col<COLS; col++)
        printf("%10d", square[row][col]);
      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always advise on checking the **return** of `scanf`. For instance with `scanf("%d", &square[row][1]);` what happens in the user accidentally enters `'a'` instead of a number? This isn't a criticism, but with the improper use of `scanf` one of the most common problems for new C programmers -- it's a missed opportunity to help them learn.

Comment: Thanks for your comments David and VolAnd. It was quick reply, and I have fixed as per your feedback. The computation works nicely, but for the "output" part, the numbers are not being properly formatted.

Comment: It yields the values all in horizontal, without considering each arr[i][j] as single entity.

Comment: @SalN85: Putting braces `{}` inside your printing for loops will probably help you see why that happens.

Comment: aah....thanks it works brilliant!!! Using shortcuts by ignoring braces screws up format..